# Android Studio XML design Layout preview width messed up

Tags: xml, android-studio

I do not know when and why it started happening, but sometime on my project building the xml design preview width became strange with the toolbar filling below the status bar (see the attached pic please). Everything's ok on the device, it just happening on the IDE.
My guess is something around the fitsSystemWindows tag on somewhere on my project, but I didn't make it to fix it.

[image]

Does anyone faced a similar problem to help me up? Appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post your xml layout and here is my xml layout so that it displays as yours  with toolbar attribute as follows:

[image: check the image here]

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
            android:layout_height="73dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

Comment: May i know what's wrong with this post.? @Brian Tompsett

Comment: I just edited in the image for you. I have no idea who downvoted it or why. However, the phrase "As far as I know" would imply you are guessing and don't have any definite knowledge. The phrase "messed up" could imply an insult to a sensitive person. But then I'm just guessing based on my experience of reading a lot of answers!

Comment: I used "As far as I know" because in the question there is no xml part mentioned and one cannot say the exact reason by seeing the preview alone.

Comment: Questions such as "Can you post your xml  layout" are not an answer and should go underneath the question as a comment (when you have enough reputation to do that)!